# How to call different functions from different controllers on the click of each tab in angular ui tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-tabset

I'm trying to call different functions from different controllers on the click of each tab using `angular-ui` tabs `directive`.

**HTML**

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Reports" ng-controller="ReportsController" ng-click="fetchReports()" id="tab1">
    <div> Reports </div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Sales" ng-controller="SalesController" ng-click="fetchSales()" id="tab2">
    <div> Sales </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

I'm getting error like this

> Multiple directives [ngController, tab] asking for new/isolated scope

**Requirement**

`I have 5-6 tabs in a page. The page should not load the data of each tab at once. It should only load data for a tab once that tab is being clicked.`

**Solution**

I have a solution to wrap the `tabset` directive with a `parent controller` such that i can have then `broadcast` events from the `ParentController` to call the functions from the respective `Child` controllers.

```
<div ng-controller='ParentController'>
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Reports" id="tab1">
      <div ng-controller="ChildOneController"> Reports </div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Sales" id="tab2">
      <div ng-controller="ChildTwoController"> Sales </div>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

But sadly i have too many pages with tabs in my application and i dont think broadcasting events for each tab from `ParentController` to `ChildController` is a good idea.
i need to know what should be a good solution for it ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use controller as syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="ReportsController as reports">
  <div ng-controller="SalesController as sales">
    <tabset>
      <tab heading="Reports" ng-click="reports.fetchReports()" id="tab1">
        <div> Reports </div>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Sales" ng-click="sales.fetchSales()" id="tab2">
        <div> Sales </div>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of what the controller would look like:

```
(function(){

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ReportsController', [
      ReportsController
    ]);

  function ReportsController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.fetchReports = function () {
      // fetch the reports! 
    };
  }

})();
```

> Source: John Papa's angular style guide recommends using the controller as
>   syntax over $scope, see [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030).

Comment: I like your solution but what about if i have 5-6 tabs..? As per this style, i then have to wrap each controllers around the tabset. I don't think this is a good idea. what do you say ?

Comment: Yes, it was more an illustration of how you can define multiple controllers if that is what you require. 

Realistically (for this scenario) you'd probably either define a single controller with all of the necessary functions (and the functionality would be further separated into services/factories), or even better see Alvaro's solution which illustrates how a directive can be created with it's own controller. All the logic for that tab is then contained in one module.

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

you should create an **[directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**:

> In this way you can use an `loop` in order to create multiples
>   directives with multiples controllers.

```js
(function() {

    angular
      .module('app')
      .diretive('directiveTab', function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: " <div> Reports </div>"//you can use templateUrl as well
            scope: {},
            controller: ['$scope',
              function($scope) {
                $scope.function1 = function(pane) {
                  
                };
              }
            ],
          };
        }
      })
```

```html
the directive will behave like controller and you can manipulate the content of each tab

<div ng-controller='ParentController'>
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Reports" id="tab1">
      <directive-tab>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason to use different controllers for different tabs is that the different tabs have different entities which are defined in different controllers. I just cant merge different controllers into one.

Comment: Sorry I'm bit confused. How would i loop for all the controllers i need and how to add the behaviour of ng-click for each tab in the directive ? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Ahmadhamza I don't know what you really need. But if you desire to create a dozen of controllers the directive is your way. If you want to costume your controller you can create multiples directives.

Comment: I understood your solution but how will it fetch request on the click of a tab. See i have 5-6 tabs on a page. Each tab fetches request to different apis. I dont want to fetch all the apis at once. It should fetch api only on click on the tab.